# How to horizontally center an A4 paper inside an A3 paper?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, geometry, lengths

I'd like to embed an A4 paper inside an A3 paper in such a way that the A4 paper be horizontally centered inside the A3 paper. (The relative vertical alignment is immaterial.)

I tried to use the following calculation in order to determine the offset of the A4 paper from the left edge of the A3 paper. Offset the A4 paper by half the following length: `\paperwidth` minus `\oddsidemargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth`.
However, this didn't accomplish the desired effect, as can be seen below.

Why did my calculation not center the A4 paper inside the A3 paper? How can I correct my code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[a3paper,portrait,showframe]{geometry}

\geometry{layout=a4paper}

\newlength{\layouthoffset}
\setlength{\layouthoffset}{.5\paperwidth}
\addtolength\layouthoffset{-.5\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\layouthoffset{-.5\textwidth}
\addtolength{\layouthoffset}{-.5\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\layouthoffset}{-.5\marginparwidth}

\geometry{layouthoffset=\layouthoffset}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: Trying to center an A4 paper inside an A3 paper]

Comment: `\oddsidemargin` is not the complete left margin (of an odd page) and `\topmargin` not the complete top margin, because TeX uses (1in,1in) as origin. BTW: I would use package `crop` to center page into another paper sheet size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the (internal) layout width of package `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[a3paper,layout=a4paper,portrait,showframe]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\geometry{layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\Gm@layoutwidth)/2\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: horizontally centered layout inside paper]

Or if you want horizontal and vertical centering, just use package `crop`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[a3,center]{crop}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: horizontal and vertical centering using package crop]